# Cannot Connect Wirelessly on Toshiba Satellite C855 with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom, toshiba

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on my Toshiba Satellite C855 and cannot connect to any wireless networks. When I run `lspci` in Terminal, it shows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
```

I have tried downloading the Broadcom STA wireless driver, and it shows as activated in Additional Drivers, but it doesn't seem to be making a difference. Please help!

Comment: Why do you try the BroadCom driver when `lspci` shows you have a Realtek?

Comment: Weird how the Additional Drivers would offer you a Broadcom STA driver when infact you have a Realtek adapter...

Comment: Did your wireless work fine at fist install, and then quit after an update?

Comment: My wireless hasn't worked since I have installed Ubuntu

Comment: Also, I have no clue what I am doing. Contrary to what my friends may think, I am no tech wizard and in fact this is my first time using Ubuntu. Simple instructions would be very helpful if anyone can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

first, in the terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
```

It's probably a good idea to remove the broadcom stuff:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

download your driver from the [Realtek site](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8188CE) (RTL8188CE)

scroll down to the Unix(linux) section, make sure you download the driver for the kernel 2.6.24 (and later). Select the mirror closest to you, and save the downloaded archive in your `Downloads` folder. Right-click and select "extract here".

in the term run

```
cd ~/Downloads/rtl_92ce*
sudo su
make install
exit
```

Wait for magic to happen. Reboot. Hopefully enjoy working wifi. Report back

Comment: `make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/build M=/home/justin/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic'
  CC [M]

Comment: /home/justin/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o
  CC [M]  /home/justin/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/rc.o
  CC [M]

Comment: `/home/justin/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/justin/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/regd.o
  CC [M]  /home/justin/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/efuse.o
  CC [M]  /home/justin/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/cam.o
  CC [M]  `

Comment: and a lot of other stuff that I don't really find a point in putting into comments. after which it left me with: `justin@justin-Satellite-C855:~/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013$`  and nothing had changed.

Comment: did you reboot? If yes post output of `lspci -v | grep -iA 10 'network'` and `lsmod`

Comment: post the output of commands in your question instead of the comment section. Output of the build process is only interesting if you get errors. You can delete these comments.

Comment: nevermind disregard what i said earlier it is working now. thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it's working and have fun in linux-land